# Create Job in Jenkins for clean Tempfiles of server

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and looking for to create job on Jenkins in order to clear tempfiles of server. Can some one please assist me how to create a job and script?
Also share steps for the same.

Comment: Do you know how to make a job? Can you write a ahell command? What have you tried? What stumps you? Put some effort [if you want help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Create a [Freestyle project](https://java2blog.com/freestyle-projects-jenkins/) and add your commands to clear files in the `Execute Shell` Build step.

Comment: As you asked - the steps are 1. create freestyle job in the jenkins server, 2. create a test script which clears tempfiles, 3. add the script's steps to the build step in jenkins, 4. test.  Please search and try to implement each step in order to successfully deliver.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.